# Simple benchmarking

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application, benchmarking

Quick and easy question that I can't find a good solution to:

What's a simple loop that will give the processor something to "chew on" for at least ten seconds? I've tried things like this but they finish in the blink of an eye:

```
int max = 300000;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    //do some random math here
}
```

Is there some kind of calculation or other operation that can go in there to take up more time and use a bit of processor power? Or another way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What is the metric you are trying to gather by doing this?

Comment: Honestly I'm just playing with different ways of showing progress in a console window, so I just need an operation that takes a little time and a few thousand iterations (or more) to complete.

Comment: You can try using `Thread.Sleep` to simulate a CPU intensive operation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx

Comment: Check out [SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx) too.

Comment: Donate your excess processor time through [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/).  The log file it creates will contain the results of a processor benchmark.  Some of their projects will happily consume excess GPU capacity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to block the thread for a period of time but not use up CPU cycles you can use `Thread.Sleep`.

If you want to waste CPU cycles for a period of time without doing anything productive, you can use `Thread.SpinWait`.

Comment: +1. Showing sample how to specify time delay for in SpinWait would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

According to your requirements:

> Is there some kind of calculation or other operation that can go in
>   there to take up more time and use a bit of processor power?

You can use DateTime and a while loop:

```
var start = DateTime.Now();
var end = start.AddSeconds(10);
while (DateTime.Now() != end) {}
```

Comment: Just don't run code like this around daylight savings time, or adjust your system clock when something like this is going on.  That's the primary problem with such code.  Oh, and the precision of `DateTime` may or may not be sufficient for your purposes.  You can resolve these issues using `StopWatch`, but there are easier ways still.

Comment: +1. quite clear code to busy wait for long time. Use UtcNow or Stopwatch instead of DateTime. @Servy's answer (+1) shows another busy wait (also SpinWait does not take time as argument) as well non-busy wait.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Using UTC still leaves you vulnerable to having the system clock changed, and does have a fairly course precision.

Answer (score 1):

You could always work on finding prime numbers, bubble sort, and things like that where you have a loop inside of a loop inside of a loop. You'd have to have a large array to go from to sort, or pick a somewhat large random number for a full 10 seconds, but they would be the best, and fastest bets I'd imagine.

Comment: You'd have to test that yourself to find that sweet spot, but once you have that done, you can carry it ahead into the future and you have your own code to benchmark test with in the future, and it gives you the option of making the test longer or shorter after you find the sweet spot. By sweet spot, I mean the number to factor if you go with primes, or the size of the array if you go bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a time based physical equation.

For example: the distance travelled by a free falling object in a certain period of time (in seconds) until it reaches X distance.

```
private float Gety(float t){float V=t*9.8f; return ((V*V)/19.6f);}
```

You can set this in a loop where your exit point will be when the return is equal or greater then a chosen distance.

By increasing and decreasing the time step you will perform more and more calculations until that distance or greater is reached.

F.e: setting initial time to 0.0f and goal distance to 500, increasing the time step from 0.01f every iteration to 0.001f will perform more calculations accordingly until the break distance is reached.

If looped within a loop and with a step of 0.0000000000001f you will do fine.

Comment: interesting ;-) you are smelling like game dev